# GAE/P storing SES connection and thread safety

Tags: python, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, thread-safety

I'm using Amazon's SES to send emails from my Python Google App Engine app.  I'd like to save the SES connection instead of creating it for every email I send.

Is this a reasonable way to do it for a multi-threded app?:

```
SES = None

def send_email_AWS(sender, to_addresses, subject, body):
    global SES
    if not SES:
        SES = SESConnection(aws_key, aws_secret)
    [other code for sending the email]
```

I don't have a good understanding of what is threadsafe and what is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example you don't have any problem **if** you are just **reading** it as if it was a constant.
**Your public variable SES is not thread safe**. That means that if for example there were many users writing to that global, then you will always be reading the last write that occurred and not per instance.

Image that threads are people. No imagine that your global variable is a public WC. Thread safe is having a Door (lock). If we didn't have a lock else everyone would be trying to do his work while another one is inside.

For your example I see:

```
SES = NONE
```

This means that each instance of your app will be reseting the SES global variable. Not a good thing.

```
global SES
    if not SES:
```

Then the first request will set it again to something. But its not safe because at the same time some other request might override it. If that is not a problem then its ok. 
What you need is to create it locally per request handler if that is the intention to be thread safe.

Answer by @voscausa shows you a good implementation example. Check it out

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to help you: http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

```
class SesConnection(object):

    _SES = None
    _aws_key = ....
    _aws_secret = ....

    _ses_lock = threading.Lock()

    @classmethod
    def get_ses(cls):

        with cls._ses_lock:

            if not cls._SES:
                cls._SES = SESConnection(cls._aws_key, cls._aws_secret)  # or put the code here
            return cls._SES
```

Or use the webapp2 app registry : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry

Comment: Why this answer is not usefull. It shows how to save a global threadsafe in Python. You only have to change the model class in an object. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, wish I could split the bounty since both answers were similar.